# Why use the Service Manager in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, service, zend-framework2, factory-pattern, service-management

lets say i have a service:

```
namespace Helloworld\Service;

class GreetingService
{
    public function getGreeting()
    {
        if(date("H") <= 11)
            return "Good morning, world!";
        else if (date("H") > 11 && date("H") < 17)
            return "Hello, world!";
        else
            return "Good evening, world!";
    }
}
```

and i create an invokable for it

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'greetingService'
                => 'Helloworld\Service\GreetingService'
        )
    );
}
```

then in my controller i could do:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $greetingSrv = $this->getServiceLocator()
        ->get('greetingService');

    return new ViewModel(
        array('greeting' => $greetingSrv->getGreeting())
    );
}
```

supposedly this make the controller dependent of the service (and the ServiceManager)

and the better solution is to create factory for that service or return a closure in the ServiceManager and create a setter in the controller:

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    private $greetingService;

    public function indexAction()
    {

        return new ViewModel(
            array(
                'greeting' => $this->greetingService->getGreeting()
            )
        );
    }

    public function setGreetingService($service)
    {
        $this->greetingService = $service;
    }
}
```

and

```
'controllers' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Helloworld\Controller\Index' => function($serviceLocator) {
            $ctr = new Helloworld\Controller\IndexController();

            $ctr->setGreetingService(
                $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()
                    ->get('greetingService')
            );

            return $ctr;
        }
    )
)
```

My question is why? Why is the second approach better than the first one? and What does it mean that  the `controller is dependent of the service`?

thanks

Comment: You can mix both approaches. You can find examples in ZfcUser module: getters use injected service if available or get one from serviceLocator.

Comment: @Xerkus ZfcUser is a pretty bad example as far as clean and performant service-configuration is concerned

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `ServiceManager` is by default injected within any ZF2 controller, as it extends the `AbstractController` implementing the `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` interface.

The second approach has a form of "[redundancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)" because, besides having already access to a `ServiceManager` instance, whenever you need to share your service among your controllers, you need to configure for each one of them the injection mechanism. As  your controllers have already a dependency vis-à-vis the ServiceManager, It would make more sense to use the first approach and register your Domain related Services to the `ServiceManager`, centralizing thus the access to the Service layer.

> <sub>Note: The following part of the answer may go beyond the scope of the question, but it aims to provide the "hidden" background of the original one.</sub>

Let's assume we're building a complex system, within which low-coupling, re-usability & test-ability are promoted. Our system is multi-layered and we built everything until the service layer. Note that until now we did not consider yet the "MVC" web layer or even opt for a given framework.

Within our Service Layer (I'll consider this layer as it is the one mentioned in the question), we assume that we adopted the [principle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w) of separation between the Business Logic and the Object Graph construction (or dependency resolution). So we have probably a couple of complex services that are constructed through factories.

Now that our service layer is built, we decide to "plug" it above ZF2. Naturally, Our services should be accessible from the controllers, as your question illustrated it, we have more than a way for doing it. However, we want to avoid redundancy and leverage what we've already built. Let's assume the following factory :

```
//The following class is a part of our Service layer
public class ComplexServiceFactory{

    private dependencyA;
    private dependencyB;

    public function buildComplexService()
    {
        $service = new ComplexService();
        $service->setDependencyA($this->dependecyA);
        $service->setDependencyB($this->dependecyB);
        return $service;
    }

}
```

What we'll do now is just to adjust (actually extend) our factory so that it becomes usable by the `ServiceManager` logic. This class can be considered as part of the mechanism used to "plug" our system to ZF2 (It's actually an [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern))

```
public class SMComplexServiceFactory extends ComplexServiceFactory implements
    Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface
{

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $sm)
    {
        $this->setDependencyA($sm->get('dependecyA'));
        $this->setDependencyB($sm->get('dependecyB'));
        return parent::buildComplexService;
    }

}
```

By doing so, we're not bringing up the object graph construction to the MVC layer **(otherwise it would be a [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) violation and an unnecessary cross-layer coupling)**. The Service Manager + our "Adapted" factories classes are in some sense our dependency resolution mechanism. The fact is that our System is still portable, we could for example opt for another system (another framework) and have a low dependency vis-à-vis the MVC platform.

Comment: this is strange. The ZF2 documentation says s better to take advantage of the ServiceManager with that factory closure

Comment: I believe that the use of a factory is appropriate if your domain service has complex dependencies (that you would probably also retrieve from the SM) and you don't want to that inside your controller.
Could you provide a link of the documentation section ?

Comment: i'm afraid i can't, the example it is from a book

Comment: so, you are saying that if i want to make my service available for other controllers or modules than i should use the second approach?

Comment: nope, use the `getServiceConfig` approach. You can declare factories (for complex services that need other dependencies) or invokables (simple services).

Comment: sure, i can use that approach, i just wanted to understand why

Answer (score 4):

Very useful question. He has been raised repeatedly. I think you can get an ACCURATE ANSWER [HERE](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/ZF2-Injecting-objects-to-a-controller-or-getting-objects-from-the-service-locator-td4656872.html)

Answer (score 3):

To add something to @yechabbis answer:

The factory pattern for the `ServiceConfiguration` is indeed for complex infrastructure or simply to not use `closures` / `callable functions` inside the configuration. This is for two reasons:

- Readability / Cleaner Code
- Performance

Setting up the factory pattern inside `getServiceConfig` is nice, clean and fast. No classes are instantiated but will so upon call of the service-key. If, however, you set up services using the closure pattern or callable function, then those classes will always be instantiated, upon every single request!

This probably is just an example thing, but the code you've shown would also best be served as a `ViewHelper`

Answer (score 0):

I think the second approach is better, which is making the controller class independent to the GreetingService. This approach will be useful when you want to use another greeting service to be consumed by the controller. You don't need to change the code in controller class at all, instead you do that by changing the service manager with that factory closure.

I believe this is the main idea of inversion of control or dependency injection, all wiring and configuration are done outside the class (in this case: controller class).

So, in my opinion, that's the reason why the second approach is the better one.